# Controlling Ehcache to not cache the zero record from query

Tags: ehcache, mybatis

I am using mybatis with ehcache for caching a query result to avoid DB hits frequency. My question is: If select query returns zero record, then ehcache is caching that and always returning zero as a result even a valid record inserted post this query execution.

*Can anyone suggest how to configure ehcache to not cache if query returns only zero record.*

```
<mapper namespace="org.test">
<cache type="org.mybatis.caches.ehcache.EhcacheCache">
    <property name="eternal" value="false" />
    <property name="maxEntriesLocalHeap" value="10000"/>
    <property name="maxEntriesLocalDisk" value="10000000"/>
    <property name="timeToIdleSeconds" value="3600" />
    <property name="timeToLiveSeconds" value="3600" />
    <property name="memoryStoreEvictionPolicy" value="LRU" />
    <property name="statistics" value="true" />
</cache> 

<select id="userInfo" parameterType="map" resultMap="userInfoList" useCache="true">
    SELECT USERNAME,USERID FROM TEST_TABLE
</select>
```

Comment: Perhaps similar to this: https://gist.github.com/bivas/1196809

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a classical invalidation problem.

Whatever logic created that additional record(s) must be responsible for invalidating the cached query. You are seeing the problem very obviously when no records are returned as a query result and you add one record that should match.

But you will face the exact same problem when your query returns `n` records, gets cached, then you add another record ... but still the query will return `n` results not `n+1`.

I would recommend looking into what mybatis offers for cache invalidation.